# Change XML Background Programmatically - Xamarin.Android C#

Tags: c#, android, xml, android-layout, xamarin

I'm trying to change a Button `background` property programmatically using `Xamarin.Android` C# but can't get it done.

Xml file:

```
... <Button
                        p1:id="@+id/BtnGo"
                        p1:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        p1:layout_height="30dp"
                        p1:paddingHorizontal="15dp"
                        p1:text="Go"
                        p1:textColor="#ffffff"
                        p1:textSize="15dp"
                        p1:background="@drawable/togglefocus"
                        p1:textAllCaps="false"
                        p1:layout_gravity="center" /> ...
```

Need to change

```
p1:background="@drawable/togglefocus"
```

To

```
p1:background="@drawable/myfocus"
```

But on execution time / Programmatically (C#).

Tried this:

```
        Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnGo);
        Btn.Click += delegate           
        {                
            Btn.Background("@drawable/myfocus"); //myfocus is an xml file in: Resources > Drawable
        };
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong you can use the SetBackgroundResouce method for this:

```
  Btn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.BtnGo);
    Btn.Click += delegate           
    {   
       Btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.myfocus);
    };
```

Good luck!
Feel free to get back if you have queries!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help :)